# Autoplayer in JavaScript/Html

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need a player like on yt.On hover to prewiew the video.Can someone help with this please.I am looking for this for a lot of time and didn't find smth to help.

Comment: Can you please provide that what you've tried so far?

Comment: If you’re talking about YouTube have a look at their docs and the “on mouse over” event.

Answer (score -1):

You should be able to achieve that sort of effect through css without any need for javascript.

Here's a simplified example:

Prepare a static thumbnail and an animated preview of the video - ffmpeg is a good tool for this.

Use css to display the appropriate file as background.

```
a {display:block; width:300px; height:200px; background-image:url("static.jpg");}
a:hover {background-image:url("animated.gif");}
```

Use something like this in the html

```
<a href="video.html">3 minute video</a>
```

Update:  Webp is almost certainly going to provide better results for a given file size than gif.  See this post over at Superuser for suggested FFMPEG settings. https://superuser.com/questions/1408120/how-do-i-generate-webp-preview-animations-using-ffmpeg

Comment: Why downvoted?  I think it's a succinct answer to the question.  I'm happy to add to the answer if it needs expansion or clarification.